# xslt add processing instruction after element

Tags: xml, xslt

In the following XML :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8" ?>
<Output>
    <Error>
        <Status>0</Status>
        <Details>No errors</Details>
    </Error>
    <Synopsis>
        <Count>451</Count>
    </Synopsis>
    <BankAccounts>
        <BankAccount AcctNo="103" CustName="Frank" BalanceAmount="" Inactive="N" NoOfAccounts="1" >
            <Addresses>
                <Address>ABC</Address>
                <Address>XYZ</Address>
            </Addresses>
        </BankAccount>
        <BankAccount AcctNo="101" CustName="Jane" BalanceAmount="10005" Inactive="N" NoOfAccounts="1" >
            <Addresses>
                <Address>LMN</Address>
                <Address>QWE</Address>
            </Addresses>
        </BankAccount>
        
    </BankAccounts>
</Output>
```

I would like to add a Processing instruction  AFTER Synopsis and BEFORE BankAccounts:

```
 <?xml-multiple BankAccount
        ?>
```

Tried with following XSLT but it is inserting PI Inside 'BankAccounts'
How do I do this using XSLT ?

```
<xsl:template match="BankAccounts">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple">
            BankAccount
        </xsl:processing-instruction>
        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the processing instruction to appear before `BankAccounts` then write it to the output before copying `BankAccounts`:

```
<xsl:template match="BankAccounts">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple">BankAccount</xsl:processing-instruction>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

In XSLT 2.0 or higher you could shorten this to:

```
<xsl:template match="BankAccounts">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple">BankAccount</xsl:processing-instruction>
    <xsl:next-match/>
</xsl:template>
```

(assuming you have the *identity transform* template or equivalent in place).

---

Or - in any version - you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="BankAccounts">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple">BankAccount</xsl:processing-instruction>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```